# Changed value of variable

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

Have you any idea what may change that value. It's code run on STM32. There are interrupts but it's almost impossible to interrupt between value initialization and the line after if statement.
My first idea is that this value is written at illegal part of memory which is used by some register.
I'm compiling the code with optimization O1 and only this function has ioptimization O0 to make analysis easier. The soft also crashes in run mode so it's not problem with debugging.
Change of value lead to overflow after few lines and crash the system. The situation repeats every time.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaQ48.png)
I don't have any idea. I've only checked if the code is correct, decralation of function, place where it is used.

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")
MonitoringParseMessStatus monitoring_ack_message(char *msg, uint16_t length)
{

    MonitoringParseMessStatus res = M_BAD_MESS;
    uint16_t single_ack_message_length = 18; // minimum len
    if(length < single_ack_message_length)
        return M_NAK;

    uint8_t len_mess = strlen(msg);
    char single_message[len_mess + 1];


    while(length >= len_mess && length >= single_ack_message_length)
    {
        memset(&single_message[0], 0, sizeof(single_message));
        memcpy(&single_message[0], msg, single_ack_message_length);

        msg += len_mess + 1;
        length -= len_mess;
        len_mess = strlen(msg);

        char * ack_ptr = strstr(single_message, "\"ACK\"");
        if(ack_ptr == NULL)
        {
            ack_ptr = strstr(single_message, "\"NAK\"");
            if(ack_ptr != NULL)
            {
                return M_NAK;

            }

            res = M_BAD_MESS;
            continue;
        }
        else
            res = M_ACK;

        char *seq_ptr = ack_ptr + strlen("\"ACK\"");
        int seq = atoi(seq_ptr);

        for(int i = 0; i < QUEUE_SIZE; i++)
        {
            if(monitoring_queue[i].set == false)
                continue;

            if(monitoring_queue[i].sequence != seq)
                continue;

            monitoring_queue[i].set = false;
            monitoring_connected_set(monitoring_queue[i].monitoring_num, true);
            monitoring_send_earliest_event();
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

Comment: *it is almost impossible* is generally the same as *it is possible*. But unless they are using an illegal pointer, no interrupt handler should be able to modify your local variable. I would assume that your debugger just displays garbage because the variable might not be used any more in that function and the register/memory location is now used by something else.

Comment: Exactly where in your debugger are you checking the variable? Where's your breakpoint? Where have you stepped? Do you actually *see* the value change from `18` to the other value?

Comment: We would need more code from that function. Is that variable used after line 662? Do you have optimizations enabled? Have you seen incorrect behaviour except wrong display in the debugger?

Comment: Is the variable needed at or after the control flow stopped? If not, the compiler is free to reassign the register or stack space to any other usage.

Comment: I've added more information and all function in question. This change of value lead to overflow and crash the system

Comment: On an unrelated note, `char single_message[len_mess + 1];` doesn't make much sense really. Especially if `len_mess` might happen to be smaller than `single_ack_message_length`. First of all change the definition of `single_ack_message_length` to `static const uint16_t single_ack_message_length = 18;` (it should never be modified, and no need to recreate it every call to `monitoring_ack_message`), then use it in the definition of `single_message`, as `char single_message[single_ack_message_length + 1];`.

Comment: Look at this sequence: `uint8_t len_mess = strlen(msg);` ... `msg += len_mess + 1;` ... `len_mess = strlen(msg);`. You have *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @WeatherVane *Maybe*, unless the "message" contains multiple messages separated by a string null-terminator, and the whole "message" is terminated by an extra string null-terminator. Which is unknown.

Comment: Please tell us the format of the "message" you receive and try to format. As @WeatherVane says you have a very potential undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude When I changed it to static it works well, but I'd like to know the reason because similiar problem may happen again.

Comment: It's no longer on the stack.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the message is given to the function as uint8_t* casted to char*. It may include few messages separated by NULL

Comment: @WeatherVane of course static isn't on stack, but there are other variables and if the reason isn't known it may happen again in different place

Comment: So each message is null-terminated. That's good. But is the last message *double* null-terminated? Is there a `"\0\0"` at the very end? If it's not then you *will* have undefined behavior as you do `len_mess = strlen(msg)` after the last message (when `msg` is pointing to invalid data beyond the last message).

Comment: Should `length -= len_mess;` be `length -= (len_mess + 1);`? That's what was added to `msg`.

Comment: Ok. I will consider and correct that but it still not explain the problem with that value at the beginning of function. After change the type to static I've noticed one more thing. I added the  screen in the topic

Comment: Until you no longer have undefined behavior, any discussion about the behavior of your code is moot. It could happen that `len_mess` is set wrongly so your loop continues even after the last message, which could lead to you overwriting some space for the local variables. When `single_ack_message_length` is `static` it's no longer stored in the same place, which it seems to keep its value, but now other local variables and data is overwritten. You must first make sure your looping and string handling is correct and you don't have any UB.

Comment: Ok. I understand I have to correct it but how undefined behaviour can change that value in first use of loop if potential weird things may happen only after that.

Answer (score 1):

Optimization might trip the debugger over. So for errors like this you need to first of all debug at the assembler level, to ensure that the assignment of the variable has indeed happened at the line you placed the breakpoint. Decent debuggers have an option to single step the machine code inlined with the C code.

Note: some expression simplification might occur even when optimization is disabled (`-O0`). Variables may still be placed in registers etc.

Other than that, local variables mysteriously changing value is often caused by stack overflow. Check the SP in your debugger when you are on this line.